# nginx.conf not found on docker image build progess

Tags: angular, image, docker, nginx

I have built docker image of Angular 6 + nginx. The error message shows that **nginx.conf** not found even I have try from different command of installing nginx I still get the same error ***file or directory of nignx not found***.

**Dockfile:**

```
FROM node:10.13.0-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm cache clean --force
COPY . ./
RUN npm install

RUN npm run build-prod 

FROM nginx:alpine as prod
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**Error Message:**

```
=> ERROR [prod 3/4] COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf                                             0.0s 
------
 > [prod 3/4] COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/nginx.conf" not found: not found
```

Comment: See if this helps -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69573002/dockerfile-getting-failed-to-compute-cache-key-nginx-conf-not-found-not-fo

Comment: try like this `COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

Comment: @Siddhant, I just realized I have missed **nginx.conf** in project....How to config that file for my Angular app?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera,  I just realized I have missed nginx.conf in project....How to config that file for my Angular app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64088021/9471852

Comment: @Siddhant, Thank you. It's helped